# I need help defining Laravel Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The two models:

```
class Event extends Model
{  // serves the same role as Post 
    public function memoryof()
    {  
        return $this->hasMany(MemoryOf::class);
    }
}



class MemoryOf extends Model
{  // serves the same role as comments
    public function event()
    {
          return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }
    
}
```

I retrieve the data like this:

```
$events=Event::with('memories')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

This SHOULD give me a collection. Instead it gives:

> "Property [memoryof] does not exist on this collection instance."

Please help me to fix this so that I get a collection.

Comment: The relation is named `memoryof`. And I think `get()` should come after `sortByDesc()`

Comment: @brombeer sortByDesc is the Collection function, so that's fine. If it was before `get()`, it would be `orderByDesc`

Comment: @aynber Ah right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$events = Event::with('memoryof')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
dd($events)
```

Comment: OK, this works. I will ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Please mark as verified this answer if its help @Dan'l